# Proving the Pythagorean theorem using dimensional analysis - stuck in finding $f(\alpha,\beta)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, euclidean-geometry, dimensional-analysis

I wanted to prove the Pythagorean theorem by the method of dimensional analysis.
I assumed a triangle like this ($AD=h, AB=a, AC=b, DB=x, DC=y$).

[image: triangle]

Then I wrote these:

$$\frac xh + \frac yh = f(\frac ah , \frac bh)$$
$$\frac ah = f(1 , \frac xh)$$
$$\frac bh = f(1 , \frac yh)$$

Normal quetions that arise at this stage are:

Can the function $f(\alpha,\beta)$ be expressed by combination of mathematical functions?

Is the general form of $f(\alpha,\beta)$ possible to determine?

Can we take another step and find the explicit form?

---

Here, of course, we know the answer. What I want is the way to achieve it.

Comment: Are there additional constraints, or relationships between $x,y,h$? The given $f(\alpha,\beta)$ doesn't appear to satisfy the conditions, unless $x y = h^2$.

Comment: @dxiv I think yea. Because a, b, and x+y are lengths of sides of a right triangle. And h is the length of the perpendecular dropped from the right angle to the opposite side. Then h will subdivide the side opposite to the right angle into two parts, I named them x and y where x and a intersect at a point of the triangle opposite to the length b. And the other subdivision will be y. Should I send an image? The main problem i talked about was actually proving the pythagorean theorem using dimensional analysis. But I didn't tell it at first.

Comment: Yes, that would give $x y = h^2$ by similarity. I think you should edit that into the question since that piece of information is quite relevant. Leaving the auxiliary variables out, what you want is basically a function $f(x,y)$ which satisfies $f(f(1,u),f(1,\frac{1}{u}))=u+\frac{1}{u}$.

Comment: @dxiv I will describe the triangle...